# Differents between $lnx^2$ and $ln(x^2)$ Find derivative

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives

I have this problem

Find derivative for $lnx^2$.

It seems that $lnx^2 \neq ln(x^2)$ since the derivative are differents using Wolfram Alpha.

I don't understand how to calculate the derivative for $lnx^2$, and the differents between these two expressions.

Could anyone clear this matter?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In normal mathematical usage $\ln x^2$ means $\ln(x^2)$; both are equal to $2\ln x$ and have derivative $\frac2x$. Of course $(\ln x)^2$ is something altogether different; if W|A interprets $\ln x^2$ to mean $(\ln x)^2$, it should give different derivatives, but that’s a non-standard interpretation of $\ln x^2$.

Comment: Do you mean $(ln(x))^2$?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott If I check the derivative for $lnx^2$ or $ln^2x$ on wolfalpha I get $\frac{2lnx}{x}$

Comment: @zoli I mean $ln^2x$ or $lnx^2$. both of them has the same derivative.

Comment: @JaVaPG: That’s incompetent programming, as far as I’m concerned.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh I see, Anyhow I meant $ln^2x$ not $lnx^2$, I seem both of them has the same derivative so I assumed their the same expression, wrong assumption of my part

Comment: @JaVaPG: That’s better, though I’m still not really happy with it: yes, it’s analogous to the well-established usage of $\sin^2x$ for $(\sin x)^2$ (and similarly for the other trig functions), but in my experience $\ln^2x$ is more often used for $\ln\ln x$.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott After reading again, I see what you meant there, Actually I didn't thought about the analogous of trig functions to the same problem great example. I do agree that notation of composition and power are confusing like as $ln^2x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here $\ln(x)^2 = (\ln(x))^2 = \ln^2(x)$ where you are taking $\ln$ of $x$ and then squaring, where as in $\ln(x^2)$ you square the $x$ first and then take $\ln$. Do you see the difference?

The derivative of the first (using the chain rule or product rule) will be:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(ln(x))^2 = 2\ln(x)\frac{1}{x} = \frac{2\ln(x)}{x}$$

The derivative of the second will be:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(ln(x^2)) = \frac{1}{x^2}2x = \frac{2}{x}$$

You could also notice that $\ln(x^2) = 2\ln(x)$ and take the derivate from there.

Comment: Oh, now I see that notation of $ln^2x$ got me confused. Now it clear, Thank you for your help!

Comment: It can be confusing if someone writes it as $\ln x^2$. At least you see the difference now, which is good.